# Can you run two servers on one cpu core?

Tags: mysql, node.js

I am thinking about buying a server but I don’t want to buy the expensive one, so can I run a node server and a MySQL database on one core or should I run them on two cores?

Comment: You can run any two things on a single core, but you probably don't want to for a live environment. For example, I use Vagrant and VirtualBox to make a test machine on my PC. The virtual machine only has 1 core and 1 gig of ram, but I can run Apache and MySQL on it. It does everything the live server can, but at about 1/16th the speed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you? Yes. As long as Node.js server and MySQL server are running on different ports - they can be up and running at the same time. But... Depending on what else you are doing and how big/complex your DB and queries are, you might want to buy a separate machine for performance reasons.